# Dynamically changing the Tab Index for the textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox

I have a requirement to accomplish to change the tab index of the cursor based on how the user wishes to perform. I am not sure what is the best way to achieve this. I have created a fiddle to ensure what is explained here is understood by all.

The requirement is the following:

- There is a table with a series of text box on all the rows and columns.
- A radio button is provided below the table for the user to be able to move through the text boxes on the table.
- Selecting "Move Horizontally" will make the cursor move from each textbox horizontally when a tab is pressed or the max length is reached.
- Selection "Move Vertically" will make the cursor move from each textbox vertically when a tab is pressed or the max length is reached.
- By default the tab indexes move vertically.
- When reaching the last textbox on either the row on the column, the cursor should automatically move to the next row or columns first textbox.

How can I achieve this dynamically when selecting the radio buttons.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2uzfT/4/embedded/result/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Complete Solution :)

**HTML**

```
<table border="1" id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Description </th>
      <th> Column1 </th>
      <th> Column2 </th>
      <th> Column3 </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> Stephen </td>
      <td><input type="text">
      </td>
      <td><input type="text">
      </td>
      <td><input type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Malcom </td>
      <td><input type="text">
      </td>
      <td><input type="text">
      </td>
      <td><input type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Judith </td>
      <td><input type="text">
      </td>
      <td><input type="text">
      </td>
      <td><input type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="selection" VALUE="V">
Move Verically<BR>
<INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="selection" VALUE="H">
Move Horizontally<BR>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    var inputBox = $('#mytable input[type="text"]').length;
    var row = $('#mytable tbody tr').length;
    var column = $('#mytable tbody tr:first td').length;

    // Vertical
    $('input:radio').change(function() {
        var self = $(this);

        if(self.val() == "V") {
            var counter = 1;
            for(i=1; i<column; i++) {   
                for(j=2; j<=row+1; j++) {
                    $('#mytable tbody tr td:nth-child('+j+')').find('input[type="text"]').attr('tabindex', counter);
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }

        else {
            $('#mytable input[type="text"]').removeAttr('tabindex');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I did a very similar solution just to see if I could. I ran into an issue -- and it looks like you have as well -- where the focus request is sent to the radio button on change, regardless. If you try to stop the focus request from sending to the radio button, it will fail to trigger the event because the change is never made (I'm guessing this is fail-safe). My only thought and solution was to capture the current inputs index (prior to the change request), and and refocus on that index after the change function (while also updating the variable that holds the index value). Thoughts?

Comment: In that case you can apply it in click event of radio button every time have to check is it true or not.

Answer (score 1):

A rough idea is below by jQuery:

```
// For columns
    var textBoxes = $('#tableid input[type="textbox"]').length;
    var rowNums = 4;

    for(i=0; i<=textBoxes; i++) {
     for(j=0; j<=rowNums; j++) {
      $('#tableid').find('tr:eq('+j+') input[type="textbox"]').attr('tabindex', i);
     }
    }
```

Row indexing can be done also same as above